# Python multiprocessing passing reference

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to pass a custom `Queue` between processes using the `multiprocessing` module.  The problem is I'm not getting all the methods coming through to the other side. According to the docs.

> A proxy object has methods which invoke corresponding methods of its referent (although not every method of the referent will necessarily be available through the proxy). A proxy can usually be used in most of the same ways that its referent can

But it doesn't say why or a way around it.  I'm wondering if anyone knows a way of doing this.

Here's a little example of what I'm trying to do.

**Server:**

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from Queue import Queue


class KeyHandler(Queue):

    def __init__(self, elements=[]):
        Queue.__init__(self)

        for element in elements:
            self.put(element)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.get, object())

    def __call__(self):
        return self


class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

keyhandler = KeyHandler(range(10))


QueueManager.register('keyhandler', callable=keyhandler)
manager = QueueManager(address=('', 50000), authkey='foobar')
server  = manager.get_server()
server.serve_forever()
```

**Client:**

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager


class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass


QueueManager.register('keyhandler')
manager = QueueManager(address=('', 50000), authkey='foobar')
manager.connect()

keyhandler = manager.keyhandler()

for elem in keyhandler:
    print elem
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client2.py", line 14, in <module>
    for elem in keyhandler:
TypeError: 'AutoProxy[keyhandler]' object is not iterable
```

The `__call__` method works but the `__iter__` method doesn't.  Can I force/workaround this somehow?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add an `exposed=['__iter__']` keyword argument to the `QueueManager.register()` call in the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **proxy**. On client add this class declaration(along with importing `BaseProxy`):

```
class KeyHandlerProxy(BaseProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('next', 'get')

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        o = self._callmethod('get')
        if object() == o:
            raise StopIteration
        return o
```

And change `register`(client's) to this:

```
QueueManager.register('keyhandler', proxytype=KeyHandlerProxy)
```

Comment: you don't need `_exposed_` field